# Wildfly management console Access Denied Insufficient Privileges

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, proxy, wildfly

I'm getting an "Access Denied: Insufficient privileges to access this interface" message while trying to access the management console of Wildfly (running on Ubuntu).

I also got an Apache2 acting as ProxyReverse for the Wildfly server. It gets requests for alias.domain.com:80 and forwards to localhost:9990.

The Wildfly access-authorization is still using simple provider, so rbac is not the culprit. Or so I believe...

When I access alias.domain.com, I'm prompted for the user/password, and I do supply the correct admin authentication data.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just wanted to let you guys know that the issue was resolved with a

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

on Apache conf.

Comment: Why did that work, I have a similar problem, but I'm using Traefik not apache

Answer (score 1):

For those using Nginx, the following directive will help with this error:

```
proxy_set_header Host $server_addr:$server_port;
```

Comment: Ok, seems like WildFly needs a port number: https://serverfault.com/a/746598/352449